# Azure Web App and Azure SQL connectionString error

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have taken the Connection String from my Azure SQL instance via the portal and pasted it into my web.config.  If I test the connection string when I create the Publishing Profile it is fine.  If I throw an exception in Global.asax to see my connection string like this: 
`throw new Exception(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);`
, it shows my correct one.  However, I still get this error:

```
{
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.",
  "ExceptionType": "System.ArgumentException",
  "StackTrace": "   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue)\r\n   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey)\r\n   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<SetConnectionString>b__18(DbConnection t, DbConnectionPropertyInterceptionContext`1 c)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.SetConnectionString(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionPropertyInterceptionContext`1 interceptionContext)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings appConfigConnection)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String name, AppConfig config)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ProviderName()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ProviderName()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DefaultModelCacheKeyFactory.Create(DbContext context)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Include(String path)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.Include(String path)\r\n   at ExpressoApi.Controllers.MenusController.GetMenus() in C:\\Users\\david\\Desktop\\ExpressoApi-master\\ExpressoApi\\Controllers\\MenusController.cs:line 17\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<GetExecutor>b__3(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()"
}
```

I've spent a couple of hours trying to fix this, I've made no progress.

Comment: seems that you're using the wrong connection string. Take a look on the official docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Simply pasting the connection string into my web.config of my Azure App does nothing. I needed to add the connection string into my PUBLISHSETTINGS file and the re-publish. Then everything works.

Comment: Please mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you